# jQuery / JavaScript - Change image in another div based on select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a select option:

```
<select>
    <option value="samsung">Samsung</option>
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="lg">LG</option>
    <option value="htc">HTC</option>
</select>
```

Later in the code, I have:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 text-center"> <!-- bootstrap stuff -->
    <img id="changePictureYo" src="Slike/uredjajS1.png"/>
</div>
```

I want the img src to change depending on the selected option. (So if I select Apple, the img src would change to Slike/iphone.png).
I have tried this:

```
<select>
    <option value="samsung">Samsung</option>
    <option value="apple" onselect="changeImage()">Apple</option>
    <option value="lg">LG</option>
    <option value="htc">HTC</option>
</select>
```

And in my `.js` file:

```
function changeImage() {
    document.getElementById("changePictureYo").src = "Slike/iphone.png";
}
```

But it is not working. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event [`onSelect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onselect) is not supported by the `<option>` tag

> The select event only fires when text inside a text input or textarea is selected. The event is fired after the text has been selected.

You need to use [`onChange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange) event.

```
<select onchange="changeImage(this)">
  <option value="samsung">Samsung</option>
  <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="lg">LG</option>
  <option value="htc">HTC</option>
</select>
```

JS :

```
function changeImage(el) {
  if (el.value == "apple") {
    document.getElementById("changePictureYo").src = "Slike/iphone.png";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much R3tep ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

```
<select id="img_change">
<option value="samsung">Samsung</option>
<option value="iphone">Apple</option>
<option value="lg">LG</option>
<option value="htc">HTC</option>
```

```
<div class="col-lg-6 text-center"> <!-- bootstrap stuff -->
<img id="changePictureYo" src=""/>
```

** jQuery code **

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('#img_change').on('change', function(){

        var img_path = 'someDir/' + $(this).val() + '.jpg';
        $('#changePictureYo').attr( 'src', img_path );
});
```

});